# How to test if a class object was created using Pytest

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, pytest

I wrote a habit tracker app and used SQLAlchemy to store the data in an SQLite3 database. Now I'm writing the unit tests using Pytest for all the functions I wrote. Besides functions returning values, there are functions that create entries in the database by creating objects. Here's my object-relational mapper setup and the two main classes:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Setting up SQLAlchemy to connect to the local SQLite3 database
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:main:', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Habit(Base):    
    __tablename__ = 'habit'
    habit_id = Column('habit_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String, unique=True)
    periodicity = Column('periodicity', String)
    start_date = Column('start_date', Date)

class HabitEvent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'habit_event'
    event_id = Column('event_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('date', Date)
    habit_id = Column('fk_habit_id', Integer, ForeignKey(Habit.habit_id))
```

One of the creating functions is the following:

```
def add_habit(name, periodicity):
    if str(periodicity) not in ['d', 'w']:
        print('Wrong periodicity. \nUse d for daily or w for weekly.')
    else:
        h = Habit()
        h.name = str(name)
        if str(periodicity) == 'd':
            h.periodicity = 'Daily'
        if str(periodicity) == 'w':
            h.periodicity = 'Weekly'
        h.start_date = datetime.date.today()
        session.add(h)
        session.commit()
        print('Habit added.')
```

Here's my question: Since this functions doesn't return a value which can be matched with an expected result, I don't know how to test if the object was created. The same problem occurs to me, when I want to check if all objects were deleted using the following function:

```
def delete_habit(habitID):    
    id_list = []
    
    id_query = session.query(Habit).all()
    for i in id_query:
        id_list.append(i.habit_id)
        
    if habitID in id_list:
        delete_id = int(habitID)
        session.query(HabitEvent).filter(
                HabitEvent.habit_id == delete_id).delete()
        session.query(Habit).filter(Habit.habit_id == delete_id).delete()
        session.commit()
        print('Habit deleted.')     
    else:
        print('Non existing Habit ID.')
```

Comment: Can you use sqlalchemy to query the database with a select statement, and compare what is (or isn't) returned from that as part of your test assertion? In other words, query the database to see if records were actually inserted or deleted.

Comment: I can do this manually by writing a function that queries the database. But how do I put this into a test assertion? There's still no output for the `add_habit` function. I could only test the new function to show that the `add_habit` function works. The same goes for the `delete_habit` function. And also that's only true, if the values have been stored to or deleted from the database by using the respective functions. (And not an excel data import e.g.)

Comment: You wouldn't need to return anything from add_habit or delete_habit. Instead the test function itself would query the database and use the results from that were as part of the test assertion. Apologies if I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: I wrote a test for the `get_habits` functions which returns all stored habits. But that still doesn't include, that the data was added using the `add_habit` function. Thus the function itself hasn't been tested properly. Maybe you could post some code, if you have something different in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can utilize the get_habits function as part of the test for add_habit.

```py
def test_add_habit():

    name = 'test_add_habit'
    periodicity = 'd'

    add_habit(name, periodicity)

    # not sure of the input or output from get_habits, but possibly:
    results = get_habits(name)
    assert name in results['name']
```